# Reformulating sum-equation to matrix/vector form.

Tags: optimization, summation, computer-science, matrix-equations

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem, where I want to minimize a function with respect to $\mathbf{n}$. However, after differentiating w.r.t $\mathbf{n}$ and setting this to 0, I get stuck. The equation is:

$
\sum_{i=1}^N 2\theta_i (\mathbf{n}\cdot(\mathbf{p_i} - \mathbf{r})) (\mathbf{p_i} - \mathbf{r}) = \mathbf{0}
$

Explanation of terms:
$\theta_i$ - Value between 0 and 1 representing a weight depending on the distance between
$\mathbf{p_i}$ and $\mathbf{r}$.

$\mathbf{n}$ - $3$ dimensional vector

$\mathbf{p_i}$ - point in $3$ dimensional space (there are N of those points)

$\mathbf{r}$ - point in $3$ dimensional space

My thoughts are to write this on matrix/vector form but I can't seem to figure this out... Any tips on how to reformulate the equation?

Comment: So the subscript of your sum is $i$? And $\cdot$ represents the inner product of the two vectors?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: It is not clear. The left side of the equation is a vector, the right side a scalar. If the operation $\cdot$ is the inner product, then the result of it scales the vector $(p_i -r)$. Correct? In that case you have then a vector on the left side

Comment: Yes that's true, sorry for being unclear. The zero on the right side is a 3x1 vector of zeros. It is basically setting the gradient to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\smn{{\small N}}
\def\t{\theta}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$Collect all of the $p_k$ vectors into a matrix, i.e.
$$P=\Big[\,p_1\;p_2\:\cdots\:p_\smn\Big]\qiq p_k = Pe_k$$
where $e_k$ is the $k^{th}$ cartesian basis vector.

Then using the all-ones vector $\big(\o=\sum_je_j\big)$ construct the matrix
$$Q = \big(P - r\o^T\big) \qiq q_k=Qe_k = \big(p_k-r\big)$$
In terms of these matrix variables, the summation becomes
$$\eqalign{
v &= \sum_{k=1}^{N}2\t_k \big(p_k-r\big)\big(p_k-r\big)^Tn \\
  &= \sum_{k=1}^{N}2\t_k\big(Qe_k\big)\:\big(e_k^TQ^T\big)\:n \\
  &= 2Q\left(\sum_{k=1}^N\t_ke_ke_k^T\right)Q^Tn \\
  &= 2QWQ^Tn \\
}$$
where $W$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the $\t_k$ weights.

Therefore, if $n$ is in the nullspace of the given matrix then $v=0.$ 
Using the pseudoinverse $(+)$ this can be expressed by the formula
$$
n = \left[I-\left(QWQ^T\right)^{\large+} \left(QWQ^T\right)\right]a
$$
where $a$ is an arbitrary vector.